# Custom List Form creation using Powershell - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, custom-list, custom-form

I have a custom List called '**IssuesList**' with 4 fields - "`IssueTitle`","`IssueID`","`IssueDesc`","`Status`"

While displaying display form I should show 3 fields expect Issue ID i.e. `IssueID` should be hidden.

and on edit form only Status field should be editable. So using SharePoint designer I created respective Edit form and display forms and changed XSLT to control the display mode on the fields.

I have everything scripted in powershell till now - creation of custom list, publishing pages, webparts etc. however I am looking for how to provision or associate these 2 list forms with IssuesList after I create the list in new site.

I have restrictions on using wsp and site/list template due to business needs. So I need to know if there is any way I can upload these 2 files after I create custom list in powershell and associate them as defaultdisplay and defauteditforms?

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Here is one script which I use often

```
$url = "Enter URL" 

$listname = Read-Host "Enter List Name"
$web = get-spweb $url 
$list = $web.lists[$listname]

#delete existing forms

$files = $list.rootfolder.files
$form1 = $list.RootFolder.files | ?{$_.url -match "dispform.aspx"}
$form2 = $list.RootFolder.files | ?{$_.url -match "editform.aspx"}
$form3 = $list.RootFolder.files | ?{$_.url -match "newform.aspx"}
$form2.delete()
$form1.delete()
$form3.delete()
$list.update()

#Upload new forms
#$dispform = $files.add($dispformurl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::FormPage)
#$editform = $files.add($editformurl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::FormPage)
#$newform = $files.add($newformurl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::FormPage)

#Set new form urls
#$editformurl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/editform.aspx"
#$dispformurl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Dispform.aspx"
#$newformurl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/NewForm.aspx"

#set new form association
$list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl = $dispformurl
$list.DefaultEditFormUrl = $editformurl 
$list.DefaultNewFormUrl = $newformurl

$list.update()
```

[Reference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yashgoel-msft/archive/2013/08/30/recreating-default-display-edit-and-new-forms-of-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Hi Amal, I have seen this script and I believe this one re-creates the forms from existing ones. My requirement is to upload new ones which are created using SharePoint designer.

Comment: Yes you can upload the forms using `Files.Add` method.. There are plenty of script available. Once you have uploaded you can set the URL as in the script.

Comment: Thanks Amal, Can you please provide a script which can do this add? Whatever scripts I looked at need to specify [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::FormPage but in powershell I am not sure how to upload file Files.Add and then assign this templatefiletype as form page. Appreciate your help

Comment: Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762291/Upload-Files-to-Library-in-SharePoint-using-PowerS) In your case you dont need to loop.